# Is there addOrUpdateRange method in EF Core 2.1?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I have searched but I could not find any method that can do if data exist update, not add.

```
 m_Context.AddRange(collection);
 m_Context.UpdateRange(collection);
```

I can write these but I want to write below

```
m_Context.AddOrUpdateRange(collection)  //no method like this
```

Is it possible?

Comment: If you're on SQL Server, you could try and hand-craft a [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) TSQL statement. But not in EF.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there addOrUpdateRange method in EF Core 2.1?

No, there is no such method.  Probably because there is no database-agnostic way to implement this that won't fail with a deadlock or key violation when multiple clients call it concurrently.